# How to change the icon of an application on the LxPanel in Lubuntu?

Tags: icons, lubuntu, customization, lxpanel

After installing Lubuntu 12.10, I decided to install IDLE 3 (from the official Ubuntu repository), but something unexpected happened: its icon gets bigger than the LxPanel and all the another application icons; the same happens on the menu when I select it from Menu > Programming > IDLE 3.

Check the image:

[image]

Note: Wasn't possible to take a printscreen from IDLE at the Menu because the printscreen action ignores the menu when it is opened.

Knowing that, I'd like to know how to change the icon of an application? Or better, if possible, how to resize this specific icon to normal size?

Comment: The icon looks like that because the Lubuntu icon theme doesn't have the correct icon, thus this icons is showed instead. As you can see the icon is oversized because it's also not in the same size as the other icons (it has a fixed size). You can get a theme that does have the icon or make your own, then change it.

Comment: The OP knows they "need" to do that. They are asking *how* to do that.